# Sorting an Array created with Inheritance by a type in child class Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, inheritance, selection-sort

I have created an array of animals that contains objects of a type *"Vertebrates"*, which is made from a number of classes that extends *"Vertebrates"*.

Essentially there a number of animal classes (ex. "Dog", "Human", etc.) that extend a "Mammals" class, which extends the *"Vertebrates"* class

I need use *Selection sort* on this array by the names given for each of these animals.

I have been trying to do this using *Comparable* and modifying the  *compareTo()* and then use **Arrays.sort(Vertebrates[] list)**

I keep getting the following exceptions
        java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1144)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1079)
    at project3.AnimalDatabase.main(AnimalDatabase.java:188)

I am not sure I am implementing the Comparable or the toCompare() part correctly.  I have been looking at other Q/A's but have not found a definitive answer

```
//Driver class for program

public class AnimalDatabase   {


public static void sort(Vertebrates[] list)
{

}

main{
//this creates a list called "animalList" of type Vertebrates
//the method in which the array is initialized and populated has been omitted here to save space.
//the list will contain a number of different animal types "Dog" "Human", etc.
     Vertebrates[] animalList = new Vertebrates[10];
}

    Arrays.sort(animalList);

for(int i=0; i<animalList.length; i++)
{
System.out.println("sorted list is " + animalList[i]);

}

//Verebrates class
//some getters and setters have been omitted, as well as a toString() method
public abstract class Vertebrates implements Comparable<Vertebrates> 
{
static int count=0;

int id;
int brainSize;
int lengthOfVertebralColumn;

Vertebrates(int brainSize, int lengthOfVertebralColumn)
{
    id=count;
    this.brainSize=brainSize;
    this.lengthOfVertebralColumn=lengthOfVertebralColumn;
    count++;

}
public String compareTo(Vertebrates other)
{
    String otherFirst = ((Mammals)other).getName();

    return otherFirst;

}

}


//Mammals class
//some getters and setters have been omitted, as well as a toString() method

public class Mammals extends Vertebrates implements Comparable<Vertebrates>    
int NumberOfTeeth;
int NumberOfFeet;
String Name;

Mammals(int brainSize, int lengthOfVertebralColumn, int NumberOfTeeth,int NumberOfFeet, String Name)
{
    super(brainSize, lengthOfVertebralColumn);
    this.NumberOfTeeth=NumberOfTeeth;
    this.NumberOfFeet=NumberOfFeet;
    this.Name=Name;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

//example of one of the animal classes
//some getters and setters have been omitted, as well as a toString() method

public class Dog extends Mammals implements Comparable<Vertebrates>  {

Dog(int brainSize, int lengthOfVertebralColumn, int NumberOfTeeth, int NumberOfFeet,        String Name, boolean domestic, CoatTypes TypeOfCoat)
{
    super(brainSize, lengthOfVertebralColumn, NumberOfTeeth, NumberOfFeet,   Name);

    this.domestic=domestic;
    this.TypeOfCoat=TypeOfCoat;

}
```

Comment: First of all `Comparable#compareTo()` method return `int` not `String`.

Comment: and the `compareTo` method for `Vertibrates` should do its comparison using field variables of `Vertibrates` not `Mammals`.

Comment: @deanosaur Yes I strongly agree.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are defining the compare logic in super class `Vertebrates` then you can use properties of super class only that is defined for all sub-classes otherwise how you will compare the objects of different sub-classes in an array.

Super-class doesn't know about its sub-classes so don't use any sub-class in super-class method.

How will you compare `Mammals` with `Animals`?